# How to fix Excel background/sheet is black

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have some issue with background in Excel. It's completely black

[image: excel bg is error]

I've been looking on Google but nothing. And I don't know which query should I type. Also I looked at the similar question in this forum, but it is totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set colors for you default app mode in Personalization?

I suggest you change the Windows Theme (Start menu > Settings > Personalization > Themes, change the theme) to check this issue.

Comment: Oh my god. It's really simple. I thought it caused by third apps I installed in the Ms. Office. Thank you Emily :)

Answer (score 0):

If you inserted a black image as background, you can delete it by going to Page Layout. On the Page Setup section, click on Delete Background.

[image: Page Layout tab]

Comment: thank you, but it's not solved.